# Release of references in PyObject when that object is a dictionary, list or text string

Tags: python, python-c-api

I have a code in [Python C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) like this:

```
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(/* some function with some arguments */);
// Do something with result
Py_XDECREF(result);
```

I'm almost sure this code is fine from the point of view of references releasing when `result` is a `PyObject*` representing a simple type (`PyBool`, `PyLong`, `PyFloat`, etc.) but I'm unsure in the following cases:

1. Dictionaries (i.e. `result` is of `PyDict` type)
2. Lists (i.e. `result` is of `PyList` type)
3. Text strings (i.e. `result` is of `PyUnicodeObject` type)

(In case 1 and 2 my doubt is due to dictionaries/lists also use `PyObject*` for it's members and I'm not sure if `Py_XDECREF()` is smart enough to remove all references used internally in the dictionary/list or if I have to implement some kind of recursive removal function)

Is my approach right also for these types?

**EDIT:** to answer the question in the comment *is the code you are using making references to the objects that are referenced by the dict or list?* a closer version to reality is the following one.

As you can see, the processing of the `result` is done in a recursive way. Not sure if `key`, `value` and the result of `PyList_GetItem(result, ix)` are making references that should be freed in some way...

```
void process(PyObject* result) {
  if (PyDict_Check(result)) {
    PyObject *key, *value;
    Py_ssize_t pos = 0;
    while (PyDict_Next(value, &pos, &key, &value)) {
      process(value);
    }
  } else if (PyList_Check(result)) {
    Py_ssize_t size = PyList_Size(result);
    for (Py_ssize_t ix = 0; ix < size; ++ix) {
      process(PyList_GetItem(result, ix));
    }
  } else if (PyUnicode_Check(result)) {
    const char* str = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(result);
    // do something with str
  } else {
    // processing other types
}

// code entry point
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(/* some function with some arguments */);
process(result);
Py_XDECREF(result);
```

Comment: is the code you are using making references to the objects that are referenced by the dict or list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for your feedback! I have provided more detail in my above question (check EDIT section)